# When I enter 2 letters it searches about one one I would search about 2 letters at once to get value

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEx3l.png)[enter image description here][2]When I enter 2 letters it searches about one one I would search about 2 letters at once to get value

```
function d() {
  var  keyy = ["ا","ب","ت","ث","ج","ح","خ","د","ذ","ر","ز","س","ش","ص","ض","ط","ظ","ع","غ","ف","ق","ك","ل","م","ن","ه","و","ي"," ",","];
  var  code = ["ي1", "س1", "و1","ع1","ي2","س2","و2","ع2","ي3","س3","و3","ع3","ي4","س4","و4","ع4","ي5","س5","و5","ع5","ي6","س6","و6","ع6","ي7","س7","و7","ع7"," /",","];

  var msg=document.getElementById("pop").value;//if value = 1س it Gives unfounded???

  var finalcode="";

  for (var i = 0, len = msg.length; i < len; i++) 
  {
    var index=code.indexOf(msg[i]); 

    if(code[index]==undefined)
      finalcode+=msg[i];
    else
      finalcode+=keyy[index];
  }

  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = finalcode;
}
```

Comment: could you provide a working code snippet and a bit more of explanation about your issue?

Comment: the code for translate wep page i would enter s1 show me a

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: if i run code gave me unfonded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what's going on, your problem is this line:

```
var index = code.indexOf(msg[i]);
```

`msg[i]` is the same thing as `msg.charAt(i)`, which only gives you a single character from the string. If you want to check two characters per index, you need to use [`String#substr(start, length)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) with a `length` argument of `2`:

```
var index = code.indexOf(msg.substr(i, 2));
```

Secondly, you should change your `for` loop if you plan to check 2 characters at a time, to something like this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = msg.length; i < len; i += 2)
```

And lastly, while the line

```
if (code[index] == undefined)
```

does work, a more robust check would be to make sure the `index` itself is valid:

```
if (index < 0)
```

All together, you get this code:

```
function d() {
  var  keyy = ["ا","ب","ت","ث","ج","ح","خ","د","ذ","ر","ز","س","ش","ص","ض","ط","ظ","ع","غ","ف","ق","ك","ل","م","ن","ه","و","ي"," ",","];
  var code = ["ي1", "س1", "و1","ع1","ي2","س2","و2","ع2","ي3","س3","و3","ع3","ي4","س4","و4","ع4","ي5","س5","و5","ع5","ي6","س6","و6","ع6","ي7","س7","و7","ع7"," /",","];

  var msg = document.getElementById("pop").value;
  var finalcode = "";

  for (var i = 0, len = msg.length; i < len; i += 2)
  {
    var index = code.indexOf(msg.substr(i, 2));

    if (index < 0)
      finalcode += msg.substr(i, 2);
    else
      finalcode += keyy[index];
  }

  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = finalcode;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Saying "not work" is not constructive. I have no idea what the problem is. Do you have an error? Can you provide an input and expected output that isn't being produced by this code? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44868923/edit) your question with these details and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm supposed to enter for example "1X" gives me "f " thr problem it gives me unfounded